# Counting using a multi-array? (Excel, VBA)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, count

I have a relatively simple task and have already found a few solutions, but I have an idea that would be far more efficient, I just don't know if it's possible to code.
Basically, I need to count animals, and their physical traits, then report on that data.  Perhaps column A is for the species, B is for their hair color, and C is their age.  I can solve this using a loop and nested if/else statements, but it balloons in size and looks very sloppy.
What I had hoped to do was *something* more like:

```
Loop
    Array(species, color, age) = Array(species, color, age) + 1
End loop
```

This turns out to be very difficult though, as some of the values I'm getting are strings (species and color) and the array function only seems to accept numbers.
Does anyone know of a way to count information like this in a very efficient manner?  If I was able to store it in an array I could have been able to print all of the results at once, which was part of my goal.

Comment: You need a variable, not the `Array` function.

Comment: If I used variables to keep track of this data, wouldn't I need a variable for every value in the report?  I'd end up needing dozens to hundreds, with each being very impractical to report on.  Using a multi-array means all the data can be stored together and reported on all at once.  Getting the data into the multi-array in an efficient manner is the hard part though.

Comment: For the sake of intent, are you counting the occurrences of the combination "species+color+age", or are you doing more analysis on the data?

Comment: For the most part I'm simply counting each combination.  There is a minor snag I need to manually check though, since almost all the data can be checked this way, but the older records recorded the animal's sex as a string and now it's a boolean.  I check the boolean, but need to search a different cell for "male/female", so I do this first and everything else is counted afterwards.

Comment: You can use a scripting dictionary and a composite key like `species|color|age`

Comment: @TimWilliams I had the same idea and was writing out the example just as you commented.

Comment: I tried using a dictionary but it didn't work..  The values I'm working with need to be reported in the same order each time, even if the value is 0.  Accidentally overlooked the comment about array variables.  This seems focused on adding a range to an array, but I don't understand how to add new data based on the string vs the range.  For a little more context, I have thousands of files here, and want to count them based on the variable name assigned to the data, rather than when someone asked for the hair color, I reference the 6th value or something.

Comment: @MichaelDunn Not sure why that would be an issue. You can look at your ordered list and check `Dictionary.Exists` to see if it has a value or is a 0. You can go through a dictionary in any order you wish, no need to follow the dictionary's default ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Dictonary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) to tally up the occurrences of each combination. The Key would be a concatenated string of the species & color & age, and the item would be the count. You would code it very similarly to your idea:

```vb
Sub Example(ItemCollection As Variant)
    Dim Counts As Object
    Set Counts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    'Loop through your data set
    Dim Item As Variant
    For Each Item In ItemCollection
        Dim species As String, color As String, age As String
        'Define species, color and age based on each item from your data set
        'Maybe they are object members, or cells in a worksheet row
        'I don't know what your data looks like.
        
        Dim Key As String
        Key = species & "|" & color & "|" & age
        
        Counts(Key) = CLng(Counts(Key) + 1)
    Next
    
    'After the data has been tallied up, the dictionary "Counts", now contains the count of occurences of each combination.
    'You can see the full list of combinations by looking at the array Counts.Keys
    'You can return a specific count from the dictionary using the key: Counts(Key) where the Key is species & color & age
    'You can get the full list of counts from the dictionary by looking at the array Counts.Items
End Sub
```

Comment: It's a good idea to add delimiter between the values, just in case (eg) you have two consecutive numeric values which run into each other. Eg.    `red|10|122` vs `red|101|22` vs `red10122`

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood something, but I tried using this and the Item found lists the animal's ID number (column A), but the species, color, and age all say "", while the key is "||".  Presumably I need to provide ranges for the species, color, and age?

Comment: @MichaelDunn If you are looping through a range, use the `Range.Rows` collection, which would make `Item` into a row of a worksheet. So `Item.Cells(1,x)` will get you a value from that row from column x. In my sample code above, I have not filled the values of species, color and age. I did not know what your data looked like, but now that I know you're using a worksheet as the source of your data, I suggest something like `species = Item.Cells(1,4).Value` which would take the value from Column D.

Comment: Sorry for the limited info and lack of pictures, I'm limited in what I can share at this time. I have a formula which found the range of data I need, and then it copies it all into a multi-array called animal_data(#,#). This is much faster than what I was doing before, but the code which counts the data is still nested if/else statements. For simplicities sake, let's say my multi array has species in 0, color in 1, age in 2, sex in 3, and the old data on sex in 4. I have been checking 3 & 4 like If Not Cells(SearchRow, 3) = "Female" OR InStr(UCase(Cells(SearchRow, 4).Value), "Female")>0) Then

Comment: OH!  Ok, it just clicked in my head what you're doing.  You're basically making a custom string based on the data, then counting how many times each appears, right?  And this is a form which allows you to extract the data afterwards?  (I've never used the methods you've used here.)

Comment: @MichaelDunn If you have an array `animal_data`, you can create a loop `For i = LBound(animal_data) To UBound(animal_data)`. where `Key = animal_data(i,0) & "|" & animal_data(i,1) & "|" & animal_data(i,2)`.

Comment: @MichaelDunn Yes. Since you're trying to count the occurrences of the combinations, I suggest using a concatenation of those values to essentially create a predictable but unique string that is associated with those values. Having a key like that allows you to store & retrieve a value in the Dictionary Object that is associated with that combination of species, color and age.